# video property and css not updating according to conditions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a video gallery with multiple videos with videos that play one at a time.
I want to remove the play button when its pressed and for it to show controls.
I have tried using useRef and useState in useEffect but nothing happen.

```
export default function VideoGallery() {
const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(
    Array(videoData.length).fill(false)
  );
  const controlsRef = useRef([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setShowControls(Array(videoData.length).fill(false));
  }, [videoData]); //to set all array elements to false.

const playVideo = (index) => {
    vidRef.current[index].play();
    showControls[index] = true;
    // controlsRef.current[i] = true;
    // console.log(controlsRef);

    console.log("show controls: ", showControls);
  };

 return (
    <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
      <div className=" flex flex-wrap -m-1 md:-m-2 ">
        {videoData.map((data, index) => {
          const videoURL = data.videoURL.replace(
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
            ""
          );
          return (
            <>
              <div
                key={data.videoURL}
                className="relative flex w-full md:w-1/3 sm:w-1/2 flex-wrap group"
              >
                <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
                  {data.videoURL && (
                    <video
                      src={data.videoURL}
                      preload="metadata"
                      volume="true"
                      controls={showControls[index] ? "controls" : ""} //controls should change
                      controlsList="nodownload"
                      ref={(el) => vidRef.current.push(el)}
                    />
                  )}
                  <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2">
                    <BsPlayCircle
                      className={`text-[#fa9204] text-6xl cursor-pointer ${
                        showControls[index] && `hidden` // css should change
                      }`}
                      onClick={() => playVideo(index)}
                      value={data.videoURL}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The values in the useState and the useRef changes(according to console.log) when user clicks on "Play" button but controls don't show and play button isn't `hidden`

Comment: `vidRef` is not defined, I think it should be `controlsRef` or maybe a copy/paste mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the state properly, what you're doing is called **mutating state** and will not trigger a re-render.

```js
showControls[index] = true;
```

Instead try this

```js
const playVideo = (index) => {
  // ...
  setShowControls((prev) => {
    return prev.map((control, idx) => {
      if (idx !== index) return control;
      return true;
    });
  });
};
```

As for the conditional it's better to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) this prevents the `className` to contain `false` is the value of `showControls[index]` is `false`. See [ternary example a6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#examples)

```js
<BsPlayCircle
  className={`text-[#fa9204] text-6xl cursor-pointer ${
    showControls[index] ? "hidden" : ""
  }`}
  onClick={() => playVideo(index)}
  value={data.videoURL}
/>
```